# "Caching" Alternatives on Process Intense Calculations

Tags: java, spring, caching

**Background:** I have done a bit of looking into Caching in Spring and it seems like a great way to save time for common read operations.  My code currently has a loop over a large number of items, where I am performing logic to see if certain other objects are connected in a way through common items.  A way to think about this is similar to a shopping website's related items showing up when you view a certain item.  The values I use to determine this are complex, but that is the basic idea.

On loading the item page there is a very long load time trying to compute and figure out which other items are related in some way as to display links to them.  Instead of computing this list every time an item page loads, I have started "caching" items with a list of their recommended items.  Many things in the system can trigger a need to recalculate these relations: adding/removing properties to items, adding/removing items, etc.

**Problem:** My "cache" is simply a singleton object containing a Map for items and their related objects.  The process of iterating through every item in the system when any change to the cache is needed is very time consuming and process intensive.  Java Caches don't seem to be the right answer due to constant changes to items.  Is there any other design patterns that I am overlooking for this design?  Caches seem to be close, but I am not sure if this problem fits into the mold of caching, due to it being a little more complex then a bulk amount of reads to a single item.

Are caches the way to go with this?  If caching isn't the right solution, what is?

Comment: I could be wrong but this smells more like a problem where you should be finding the most efficient way to *model* your objects using a *data-structure* that is best suited for such problems. The Cache is where the references will go eventually but the structure that holds the data needs to be thought of properly.

Comment: I agree with @CKing there. You seem to have a problem because you only have one physical entity (`Item`), and you have a logical entity `ItemRelation` (with type property and whatever else is on there). Since there is such a big need in `ItemRelation` data, why not materialize the relations as a physical entity to be stored in similar media your items are stored? This way you can save yourself a trouble by computing relations only when some changes happen, and rest of the time you just read what's available in relations datastorage.

Comment: @CKing @m-prokhorov I'll try and keep it generic:  `Item` has a `Set<Property>`.  `Property` tracks more or less a key/value pair think along the lines of like `Color : Blue` where `Color` is an `Attribute` and `Blue` is a `Value`.  The `Attribute` & `Value` exist on their own (complex DB is complex) so everything is all linked up.

I am only updating this "cache" when stuff changes, but the issue is it is still looping through every `Item` in the system to recheck its `Property` to see if the new change affects the "cache" (add/remove/whatever).
`Property` holds handles to `Item` & others.

Comment: The issue is that we still have to loop through EVERY `Item` on changes to check for updates.  I don't think the time consuming bit is the retrieval of the data (I think), I think it's on the sheer number of items.  Hence why I am trying to figure out if there is a design pattern similar to caching that serves this purpose for large calculated data loops.

Comment: You could maintain two caches, one which contains items and one which contains item relationships. So your item cache will look something like `Map<String,Item>` where the key is the unique identifier for each item. Your item relationship cache will look like `Map<String,Map<String,List<Item>>>` where the key is the attribute type (e.g "color") and value is again a `Map` where key is the actual color (e.g "green") and finally the List of items that have the color green. These two caches should be maintained independently. Does this make sense?

Comment: @Cking that makes sense.  I'm gonna take a stab at the object design a bit.  I think this is another way to look at it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that caches are not a solution for your problem, but they might help you in reaching a solution.

For example instead of caching the created items another approach is to cache information that rarely changes but is crucial to create the lists.

Spring function based caching (ie @Cachable) might come in handy, either for caching or invalidation.

The next level is to examine different types of caches (ie. [redis](https://redis.io/)) and what they offer in terms of algorithms, sorting and Pub/Sub.